# How to automate the selection of the indentation length depending on the length of the word?

Tags: latex3

How here (%%% Definitions>>>\setlist>>>leftmargin=) to automatically substitute the distance from the term to the definition depending on the length of the word (highlighted in yellow) so that the definition is not under the term (highlighted in red).

There are both short and long terms in the text, so this should be calculated automatically.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы


%%% Оформление текста
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Начертание шрифта
\usepackage{xcolor} % Изменение цвета


%%% Определения
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{worddefs}{description}{1}
\setlist[worddefs]{font=\sffamily\bfseries, labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=6em, style=sameline}

%%% Создание maketitle
\author{Птичка Химичка}
\title{Химия с нуля} 
\date{}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\Huge\bfseries\@title \par}%
        \vskip 1.5em%
        {\large
            \lineskip .5em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \@author
            \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        {\large \@date}%
    \end{center}%
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \section*{Основы химии}
    
    \begin{worddefs}
        \item[\textcolor{purple}{Химия} -] наука о веществах, их свойства, строение и превращениях, происходящих в результате химических реакций.

        Т.к. все вещества состоят из атомов и молекул, то химия занимается в основном, изучением взаимодействий между атомами и молекулами, полученными в результате таких взаимодействий.
        
        \hfill
        \hrule
        \hfill
        
        \item[\textcolor{purple}{Вещество} -] то что имеет массу (её не имеют волны, поля и.т.д), но не имеет определенной формы.
    \end{worddefs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place each item in its own table (instead of using `enumerate`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\textdef[2]{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX}#1&#2\\\end{tabularx}}
\begin{document}
\textdef{\textcolor{purple}{Химия} -}{наука о веществах, их свойства, строение и превращениях, происходящих в результате химических реакций.}\bigskip
\hrule
\ \bigskip\\
\textdef{\textcolor{purple}{Вещество} -}{то что имеет массу (её не имеют волны, поля и.т.д), но не имеет определенной формы.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, but the definitions are at different distances from the left edge, and it doesn't look very nice, and if you align on the left side, a lot of spaces appear. (https://dropmefiles.com/NZbkA)

Comment: @DarMaster I just updated the solution to better fit your request.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!